# action script 2.0 simple string comparing with conditional statement

Tags: actionscript

So I have this crazy problem with comparing 2 strings in ActionScript 2.0

I have a global variable which holds some text (usually it is "statistic") from xml feed

```
_root.var_name = fields.firstChild.attributes.value;
```

when I trace() it it gives me the expected message

```
trace(_root.var_name); // echoes "statistik"
```

and when I try to use it in conditional statement the rest of code is not being executed because comparing :

```
if(_root.overskrift == "statistik"){
    //do stuff
}
```

returns false!

I tried also with:

```
if(_root.overskrift.equals("statistik"))
```

but with the same result.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: and what about: `if( _root.overskrift.indexOf( "statistik") >= 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

Years later but on a legacy project I had the same problem and the solution was in a comment to this unanswered question. So let's make it an anwer:

Where `var a:String="some harmless but in my case long string"` and `var b:String="some harmless but in my case long string"` but `(a==b) -> false` the following works just fine: `(a.indexOf(b)>=0) -> true`. If the String were not found indexOf would give -1. Why the actual string comparison fails I coudn't figure out either. AS2 is ancient and almost obsolete...